# Confusion regarding Identity and Inverse vector for a real vector space.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Is it necessary that for every real vector field , the inverse vector should be $0$ or $(0,0)$ or $\underbrace{(0,0,\dotsc,0)}_{n \text{ times}}$ depending on whether output belongs to $\mathbb{R},\mathbb{R}^2,\dotsc,\mathbb{R}^n$?

Let's assume that we have a vector space defined as -
$V=\{(1,x) \mid x \in \mathbb{R}\}$ over field $F=\mathbb{R}$, where $u=(x,y)$, $v=(x',y')$ and $+,\times$ are defined as
$$u+v=(1,x+x') \\ 
a.u=(1,ax) $$
where $a \in \mathbb{R}$. So in this case will it not be possible to get an inverse vector as the output will always be in the form $(1,x)$ ?

So is any other output acceptable other than $0$ or $(0,0)$ or $\underbrace{(0,0,\dotsc,0)}_{n \text{ times}}$ depending on whether output belongs to $\mathbb{R},\mathbb{R}^2,\dotsc,\mathbb{R}^n$?

Comment: `the inverse vector should be 0, or (0,0), ...`  does not make sense. Inverse of what, with respect to which operation?  Also please use [mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to write math.

Comment: @P.Siehr For every u belonging to V. There must exist a -u such that u-u= 0. So if the vector space is real then is it true that the output must belong to 0 or (0,0) or (0,0,..... n times) depending on whether output belongs to R,R2,...,Rn ?

Comment: @AashishLoknathPanigrahi I have edited your question to improve grammar and add MathJax for the mathematical expressons; it was practically illegible without.

Comment: @Chappers thanks: )

Comment: You seem to have the notion of "inverse" and "identity" mixed up.

Comment: @user328442 sorry that was a typo. I mixed Inverse with identity.

Comment: @AashishLoknathPanigrahi where you say "inverse vector" do you mean "identity vector"?

Comment: @RobertFrost I am simply asking that here the output will always be in the form (1,x) irrespective of whatever input is taken which is not equivalent to (0,0) belonging to R^2.  So can  (-x,y) or (-x,-y) be considered as inverse vectors such that (1,0) will be output ??

Comment: The first sentence still does not make sense to me. You probably want to ask: Is the additive neutral element $v_0$ of a vector space $V=ℝ^n$, $n=1,2,…$ always of the form $$v_0=\underbrace{(0,…,0)}_{n \text{ times}}.$$ Then again, your example space $V=\{(1,x):...\}$ is not one of these vector spaces $ℝ^n$.  So are you asking for the neutral element in an arbitrary vector space?

Answer (score 1):

We can have identity vectors that look different that $0$ or $(0,0), (0,0,0)$ etc.

With your example, we clearly have that $V$ is a vector space over the field of real numbers given the operation that you defined but it is not a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^2$ under the usual definition of component-wise addition and scalar multiplication since the identity and inverse elements will be different. (And $(0,0) \notin V$ among other things)

An inverse element, x, for a vector $v \in V$ must satisfy $x+v = v+x = 0$ for whatever the zero vector is. The zero vector must satisfy $0+v=v+0=v$ for any $v \in V$.

Let $v = (1, y) \in V$. Then the identity can be found: $$0+v = (1, z) + (1, y) = (1, y).$$

So, $z=0$ and the zero vector must be $(1,0).$

Next, we can use this to see what inverse elements look like.

Using the same $v$ from before and $x= (1, w)$, we have $$x+v=0 \Longrightarrow (1, w) + (1,y) = (1,0).$$

So, the inverse of $v = (1,y)$ is $(1,-y).$